# null is not an object when evaluating this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of items and I would like only one of them to be highlighted at any given time. I wrote the following code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({indexHighlighted: 0});
}

selectItem = (i) => {
    this.setState({indexHighlighted: i});
}

checkIfHighlighted = (i) => {
    i == this.state.indexHighlighted;
}

render() {
    return ( 
        <FlatList
            data={myData} 
            renderItem={ ({item}) =>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.selectItem(item["indexNr"])}>
                    <ShoppingListItem
                        key={item["indexNr"]} 
                        highlighted = {this.checkIfHighlighted(item["indexNr"])}
                        orderInList={item["indexNr"]} />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            }
            keyExtractor = {(item, index) => index}
        /> 
    );
}
```

When I run this code, I get 
`null is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.indexHighlighted')`.

Why would `this.state` be `null`? Can it be `null` if I set it from the constructor?

If yes, then how can I initialise it in due time such that error doesn't appear?

Comment: In your constructor initialize the state like `this.state = {indexHighlighted: 0};`, instead of using `setState`.

Comment: You also need to `return i == this.state.indexHighlighted;` with the curly brace function syntax. You're missing the `return` keyword.

Comment: @Prakashsharma you should write an answer.. the only person who knows what they are talking about.

Comment: @Prakashsharma after they had seen your comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 syntax mistake.

One is that you are not settings state correctly. Second you are executing the function rather than passing it as a property.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {indexHighlighted: 0};
}

 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.selectItem(item["indexNr"])}>
   // ...
 <TouchableHighlight />
```

Answer (score 0):

you must bind your function in the `constructor` and if you want send an argument to your function you should define an outer function in jsx. Also you shoul use return in `checkIfHighlighted` fucn.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
       indexHighlighted: 0
     };
     this.checkIfHighlighted = this.checkIfHighlighted.bind(this);
     this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
        }

...
checkIfHighlighted (){
  return i == this.state.indexHighlighted;

}
...
```

jsx :

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.selectItem(item["indexNr"])}}>
                    <ShoppingListItem
                        key={item["indexNr"]} 
                        highlighted = {this.checkIfHighlighted(item["indexNr"])}
                        orderInList={item["indexNr"]} />
                </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: No need to bind. OP is using arrow function.

Comment: I think `this` will refer undefined when it is not binded in the selectItem function.

Comment: If you use arrow function then you dont need to bind. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Yes but `checkIfHighlighted`  and `selectItem` are not arrow functions. Am I wrong? Also thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: They are arrow functions. Look at the question.

Comment: Yeap I missed it. Thank you again

Answer (score -2):

In constructor you should use this syntax:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
       indexHighlighted: 0
     };
    }
```